# SQL Server - insert/update record in/from multiple tables using node.js, react, express.js

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a node.js + react app. I have my records stored in related tables.

What I get/send from/to the UI is JSON.

The JSON is split in actual SQL TABLES and all tables are related according to JSON structure

I cannot share the schema with you but what I am asking in a scenario of an update or insert command what strategy should I follow ?

- should I do the insert/update for each record in each table as separate inserts
- should I do it in the client side, and foreach object in my array call insert/update db actions?

Comment: How would you do one strategy without the other? It sounds like your only option is to enumerate over every object property of the data-object and insert into tables appropriately.

Comment: I am trying to fish for some advice on how to do it as best practice, that came of the top of my head while thinking about it so I would like to know what other strategies are available

Comment: Oh is this a question of whether the client or server should handle this? If so, the server should definitely handle it. The client should know nothing at all about the internal database structure

Comment: I mean, the nodejs will handle it right, it will receive a JSON from UI. Now the nodejs can loop through every object properties. If my JSON contains objects like: store, product, customer then nodejs will trigger db update for each of these objects. This is what I taught about. The other part was where the whole JSON goes to db and there a stored procedure can do the magic ...

Comment: What you want is to have the business service layer handle business logic and parsing the serialized data, typically you would then have a data access layer that in turn takes the business logic layer's result and inserts it into/updates it in the database. Node.js is already optimal for JSON parsing on its own, no need to have SQL Server do it

Comment: Plus if you parse it in SQL Server, once you decide the data object needs some sort of business rules applied to it you now have business rules in the database, and writing concise business logic in SQL is a lot harder than it is in node.js

Comment: Thanks mate. Things are much clear now.